# How can I make trigger in Oracle SQL to change rows in another table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, database-trigger

I need to write a trigger in my SQL code that changes values in table A(Asortyment) that is connected with table B(Historia_Zamowien) with relation Many-Many. To connect A and B I use table C(Zamowienia_Asortyment).

[How it looks like in relational model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awW2B.jpg)

I need to get to `Asortyment.Dostepnosc` through `Zamowienia_Asortyment` after `INSERT ON Historia_Zamowien` and change values to `0`. I wrote some code that doesnt work and i have no idea what is wrong. Would you help?

```
CREATE TRIGGER "Zmiana_Dostepnosci_Po_Zamowieniu"
AFTER INSERT ON "Historia_Zamowien"
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE "Asortyment"
    SET tab1."Dostepnosc" = 0
    FROM "Asortyment" tab1 JOIN "Zamowienia_Asortyment" tab2 ON tab1."ID_sprzetu" = tab2."ID_sprzetu"
         JOIN inserted tab3 ON tab2."Numer_zamowienia" = tab3."Numer_zamowienia"
    WHERE tab1."ID_sprzetu" = tab2."ID_sprzetu" AND tab2."Numer_zamowienia" = inserted."Numer_Zamowienia"
END;
/
```

After i run the code i get:

```
Error(1,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(3,5): PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
Error(7): PLS-00103: Endountered symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with    <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>    <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge json_exists json_value json_query    json_object json_array
```

Comment: What des `inserted` mean in your query ? It relates to the newly created row in `Historia_Zamowien` ?

Comment: Im not 100% sure but i hope it works just like you said, cuz i tried many, many options to make it works and none of them worked, and after this one i gave up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your SQL :

- in Oracle you cannot use `JOIN` within an `UPDATE` ; I replaced it with a `WHERE EXISTS` correlated subquery
- you have repeated conditions in `JOIN`s and `WHERE` clause, I simplified that
- to refer to the newly inserted row in `Historia_Zamowien`, use the  `:NEW` keyword (you seem to use `inserted`)

Try :

```
CREATE TRIGGER "Zmiana_Dostepnosci_Po_Zamowieniu"
AFTER INSERT ON "Historia_Zamowien"
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE "Asortyment" tab1 SET tab1."Dostepnosc" = 0
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
         FROM "Zamowienia_Asortyment" tab2 
         WHERE tab2."ID_sprzetu" = tab1."ID_sprzetu"
         AND tab2."Numer_zamowienia" = NEW."Numer_Zamowienia"
    )
END
/
```

Comment: Your code seems to be working well, but I found another problem, that i have to add rows `Historia_Zamowien`, then add rows to `Zamowienia_Asortyment` and then change the values to `0` because before that i search in "empty" table. Anyway you helped me a lot, thank you and good luck :D